# Phonegap event listeners not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

Phonegap 3.4.0, jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.
I've posted other questions about issues with my app, but the underlying problem seems to be that my event listeners are not working correctly. This could either be that I've done it wrong, or there is a conflict.

I have this code in my javascript file:

```
function onPause() {
    initialize();
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}

function onResume() {
    initialize();
}

function onBack(e) {
    alert("running");
    if($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( 'getActivePage' ).attr( 'id' ) == "login") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("halted");
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBack, false);
}

$( "body" ).load(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});
```

However, none of the functions, `onPause`, `onResume`, or `onBack` are ever called. Which leads me to believe my event listeners are not correct or something is wrong. Am I missing something? Is there something I can check that might be causing this problem?

Comment: 1) did you add `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` correctly? 2) check if an `alert` fire inside deviceready. 3) check for errors in eclipse logcat if possible 4) what is this initialize() do!! check if that is failing.

Comment: @AtanuCSE I have not added the cordova.js, it was my understanding that Phonegap  Build adds that in automatically. I will toss in an alert inside deviceready for my next build. I don't have eclipse so that will be difficult. And `initialize` is a custom function that works perfectly fine, it is just never called during those events.

Comment: as an issue I found one time long ago, any chance you are including the 'hello world' index.js that rolls with new Cordova? I had an issue where I couldn't get anything in my onDeviceReady to fire and it turned out I still had the index.js from the original project included in my html, causing a namespace issue with the onDeviceReady function

Comment: This is all done by scratch in notepad++ in pure jQuery/HTML and then zipped and uploaded to phonegap build. The only scripts I have are libraries and my code. Unless Phonegap build is adding that in...

Comment: @AtanuCSE I added an alert to the `onDeviceReady` function, and I never receive that alert, regardless of where I put the event listener. So that is almost definitely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is deprecated since version 1.8 of jQuery. So your event listeners are probably never added. [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) would be the replacement for [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

But you should think about using it anyway. At least in the way you are doing it now. Because there is no need to wait for the body to load to add an event listener and it might be possible that the "deviceready" event fires before the body is ready. So you would miss the event. I actually don't know if this could ever happen in a cordova app, but I wouldn't take the risk.

Comment: I have tried it in both $(document).ready(function(){}); and outside all jQuery handlers by itself, and none of them work. The Phonegap documentation says to put it in the body onLoad so I was just following instructions.